# Getting Document Collection in Lotus Notes using the Form UNID

Tags: lotus

I have the UNID of a Lotus Notes form. can i use this UNID to get the Document Collection of that form ??

I am using the NotesDatabase.Search() method to get the document collection. But this query only works if it is provided with the Form Name. Does not works works with the Form UNID.

I am trying to do this because in my application there are two forms with the same name and Alias name.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: This is NOT possible.

Documents are linked to the Form via their own Form- item. This is a textitem and contains the alias of the form they were created with. There is NO further relation between the form that was "really" used when creating a document. As soon as you create another Form with that alias and delete the old one, all documents will use the new one. As long as there are 2 forms with the same alias, one of them will be used by chance (usually the one with the smaller NoteID will be used, but this can not be guaranteed).

If your question is to find out, which documents where created with which of the forms the only possibility is to select them according to special fields in the forms. If e.g. one form has an item "CreatedDate" and the other does not, then you could select `@IsAvailable( CreatedDate )`

Unfortunately if you open a document that was created with the "old" form and save it, it will also have the new item... So this will never be a 100% solution.

To make it even harder: One could create a document using LotusScript and in the end just fill the Form- item: `doc.Form = "SomeForm"`. Then the document was not created with either of your two forms...